# how to show prograss bar before loading the image in Picasso. and then if image is loaded then start stories progressview in android

Tags: android, firebase, github

I am working on the project to create the stories like whatsapp or instagram.

we are using the library from [Github](https://github.com/shts/StoriesProgressView)

Our image are loaded from firebase.

but the problem is that stories start with loading the image because image size is large.

```
@Override
    public void onFirebaseLoadSuccess(final List<Movie> movieList) {
        storiesProgressView.setStoriesCount(movieList.size());
        storiesProgressView.setStoryDuration(1500L);



    Picasso.get().load(movieList.get(counter).getImage()).into(imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            storiesProgressView.startStories();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {

        }
    });

    storiesProgressView.setStoriesListener(new StoriesProgressView.StoriesListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNext() {

            if(counter < movieList.size()){
                counter++;
                Picasso.get().load(movieList.get(counter).getImage()).into(imageView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrev() {

            if(counter > 0){
                counter--;
                Picasso.get().load(movieList.get(counter).getImage()).into(imageView);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            counter = 0;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Completed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think its possible with picasso unless you fork picasso and update it. I had the same problem as you and i was decided to use Glide instead. It's so much better than picasso.

Comment: Check this out and replace picasso with glide : https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: @twenk11k How do i change this code into glide then

Answer (score 0):

Picasso doesn't has a function to check when load started so i highly recommend you to use Glide instead of Picasso.

Here, you can show progress bar when image loading is started via onLoadStarted() function :

```
  Glide.with(this).load(movieList.get(counter).getImage()).into(new Target<GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadStarted(Drawable placeholder) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
            storiesProgressView.startStories();

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCleared(Drawable placeholder) {

        }

        @Override
        public void getSize(SizeReadyCallback cb) {

        }

        @Override
        public void setRequest(Request request) {

        }

        @Override
        public Request getRequest() {
            return null;
        }

    });
```